# PHP Links Regex

Tags: php, regex

How to modify this function so it could add `target="_blank"` attribute to external links?
Take the default domain as `example.com`

```
function makeLinks($text){
 if(eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text) != $text){ 
  $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
  return $text;
 } 
 $text = eregi_replace('(www\.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $text); // ([[:space:]()[{}]) deleted from beginnig of regex 
 $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text); 
 return $text; 
}
```

Comment: [`ereg_replace()` and `eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/ereg_replace) are deprecated. You should switch to PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    class HtmlLinkUtility
    {
        public static $BaseDomain = null;
        public static function ReplaceEmailToHtmlLink($source)
        {
            return preg_replace('/([_.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})/i',
                '<a href="mailto:\1">\1</a>', $source);
        }

        public static function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source)
        {
            function replaceUrl($groups) {
                $url = $groups[1];
                return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . (strpos($url, HtmlLinkUtility::$BaseDomain) !== false ?
                    ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>' . $url . '</a>';
            }

            return preg_replace_callback('!(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)!i',
                replaceUrl, $source);
        }

        public static function ReplaceTextDataToLinks($source, $baseDomain)
        {
            self::$BaseDomain = $baseDomain;
            return self::ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink(self::ReplaceEmailToHtmlLink($source));
        }
    }

    echo HtmlLinkUtility::ReplaceTextDataToLinks(
        "test@test.com<br />http://www.google.com/<br />http://www.test.com/",
        "google.com"
    );
?>
```

Could not see why you would use two expressions that basically matched/replaced the same thing. Simplified your method a little.

Also, for the record. HTML is not *regular* in that way that it in any form could be parsed by a regular expression. Though, for simple cases like the one above, it works well.

Comment: I need to match the difference between example.com (my) and example1.net(external)

Comment: But it still does not work as I want it to. Give me 2min and I'll give you a fully working example.

Comment: Try the new code. It should be able to handle the URL's in the way that you wanted. In the example, "google.com" is the base domain. You would of course switch this with your own.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML is unestable, expensive and, in a word, a hell. You should use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).